# Get count of a field and use that as a new column for each line item in a new table

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a new table which sources data from 2 different tables. Here is how the layout is supposed to look?

```
acc_no | id | total_num | status
```

The total_num column is supposed to have the count value for each line item having same acc_no. Below is the code I'm using to get counts for each acc_no.

```
select cnt.acc_no, count(1) as cou from (
    select a.acc_no, a.id, b.status
    from table1 a
    inner join table2 b
    on a.sid = b.sid
    where b.type = 'SMT'
    and b.status = 'Active'
    order by a.sid, a.dt desc
) as cnt
group by cnt.acc_no
order by cou desc;
```

After getting the counts, let's say there are 3 different acc_no values

```
| acc_no | cou |
| -----  | ----|
| 313    | 3   |
| 152    | 2   |
| 147    | 4   |
```

All good until here. Now I need the count of acc_no to be updated as a number for each line item. For eg., in the below table, since the count is 3 for acc_no 313, each line item having acc_no 313 should have the total_num column value as 3. My new table is supposed to look like this. I'm not sure how to go about doing this:

```
| acc_no | id | total_num | status |
| 313    | ef | 3         | active |
| 313    | ad | 3         | active |
| 313    | hf | 3         | active |

| 152    | hf | 2         | active |
| 152    | es | 2         | active |

| 147    | xw | 4         | active |
| 147    | ef | 4         | active |
| 147    | te | 4         | active |
| 147    | mh | 4         | active |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your tables so I created `t_sub` (`t` as "table", `sub` as "subquery) which represents what your subquery (inline view) returned:

```
SQL> select * from t_sub;

    ACC_NO ID STATUS TYP
---------- -- ------ ---
       313 ef Active SMT
       313 ad Active SMT
       313 hf Active SMT
       152 hf Active SMT
       152 es Active SMT
       147 xw Active SMT
       147 ef Active SMT
       147 te Active SMT
       147 mh Active SMT

9 rows selected.
```

Instead of `count` in its aggregation form, use its **analytic** form instead to get desired result:

```
SQL> select cnt.acc_no,
  2    cnt.id,
  3    count(*) over (partition by cnt.acc_no) total_num,
  4    cnt.status
  5  from t_sub cnt
  6  order by cnt.acc_no desc;

    ACC_NO ID  TOTAL_NUM STATUS
---------- -- ---------- ------
       313 ef          3 Active
       313 ad          3 Active
       313 hf          3 Active
       152 hf          2 Active
       152 es          2 Active
       147 xw          4 Active
       147 ef          4 Active
       147 te          4 Active
       147 mh          4 Active

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

Or, in your case:

```
select 
  cnt.acc_no,
  cnt.id,
  count(*) over (partition by cnt.acc_no) total_num,
  cnt.status
from (
      select a.acc_no, a.id, b.status
      from table1 a inner join table2 b on a.sid = b.sid
      where b.type = 'SMT'
        and b.status = 'Active'
) cnt
order by cnt.acc_no desc;
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I'm not that proficient in SQL, so wasn't even aware we could do a partition on Count. I thought we could use partition only on ROW_NUMBER().

Comment: You're welcome. When you have some time to spare, have a look at analytic functions' documentation.